# Smartface text font type selection

Tags: smartface.io

I have imported from "Font Import Wizard" additional new font but although i select the text new imported types of font it displays default font type.
Some additional setting exist?

Comment: There is a document about adding new fonts: smartface.io/developer/guides/project/font-usage  After adding new font try to close ide and after that open it again. Also you can try to delete Object folder under your project's data folder. If none of them works can you please tell the device name and OS version you use?

Answer (score 0):

It was due to simulator. when you export xcode everything is ok.